# Python: confusion between types and dtypes

Tags: python, numpy, types, unsigned-integer

Suppose I enter:

```
a = uint8(200)
a*2
```

Then the result is 400, and it is recast to be of type uint16.

However:

```
a = array([200],dtype=uint8)
a*2
```

and the result is

```
array([144], dtype=uint8)
```

The multiplication has been performed modulo 256, to ensure that the result stays in one byte.

I'm confused about "types" and "dtypes" and where one is used in preference to another.  And as you see, the type may make a significant difference in the output.

Can I, for example, create a single number of dtype uint8, so that operations on that number will be performed modulo 256?  Alternatively, can I create an array of type (not dtype) uint8 so that operations on it will produce values outside the range 0-255?

Answer (score 14):

The simple, high-level answer is that NumPy layers a second type system atop Python's type system.

When you ask for the `type` of an NumPy object, you get the type of the *container*--something like `numpy.ndarray`. But when you ask for the `dtype`, you get the (numpy-managed) type of the *elements*.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> arr = array([1.0, 4.0, 3.14])
>>> type(arr)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Sometimes, as when using the default `float` type, the element data type (`dtype`) is equivalent to a Python type. But that's equivalent, not identical:

```
>>> arr.dtype == float
True
>>> arr.dtype is float
False
```

In other cases, there is no equivalent Python type. For example, when you specified `uint8`. Such data values/types can be managed by Python, but unlike in C, Rust, and other "systems languages," managing values that align directly to machine data types (like `uint8` aligns closely with "unsigned bytes" computations) is not the common use-case for Python.

So the big story is that NumPy provides containers like arrays and matrices that operate under its own type system. And it provides a bunch of highly useful, well-optimized routines to operate on those containers (and their elements). You can mix-and-match NumPy and normal Python computations, if you use care.

There is no Python type `uint8`. There is a constructor function named `uint8`, which when called returns a NumPy type:

```
>>> u = uint8(44)
>>> u
44
>>> u.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> type(u)
<type 'numpy.uint8'>
```

So "can I create an array of type (not dtype) uint8...?" No. You can't. There is no such animal. 
You can 
do computations constrained to `uint8` rules without using NumPy `arrays` (a.k.a. NumPy scalar values). E.g.:

```
>>> uint8(44 + 1000)
20
>>> uint8(44) + uint8(1000)
20
```

But if you want to compute values mod 256, it's probably easier to use Python's mod operator:

```
>> (44 + 1000) % 256
20
```

Driving data values larger than 255 into `uint8` data types and then doing arithmetic is a rather backdoor way to get mod-256 arithmetic. If you're not careful, you'll either cause Python to "upgrade" your values to full integers (killing your mod-256 scheme), or trigger overflow exceptions (because tricks that work great in C and machine language are often flagged by higher level languages).

Answer (score 10):

The `type` of a NumPy array is `numpy.ndarray`; this is just the type of Python object it is (similar to how `type("hello")` is `str` for example).

`dtype` just defines how bytes in memory will be interpreted by a scalar (i.e. a single number) or an array and the way in which the bytes will be treated (e.g. `int`/`float`). For that reason you don't change the `type` of an array or scalar, just its `dtype`.

As you observe, if you multiply two scalars, the resulting datatype is the smallest "safe" type to which both values can be cast. However, multiplying an array and a scalar will simply return an array of the same datatype. The [documentation](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) for the function `np.inspect_types` is clear about when a particular scalar or array object's `dtype` is changed:

> Type promotion in NumPy works similarly to the rules in languages like C++, with some slight differences. When both scalars and arrays are used, the array's type takes precedence and the actual value of the scalar is taken into account.

The documentation continues:

> If there are only scalars or the maximum category of the scalars is higher than the maximum category of the arrays, the data types are combined with `promote_types` to produce the return value.

So for `np.uint8(200) * 2`, two scalars, the resulting datatype will be the type returned by [`np.promote_types`](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~pbechler/numpy_doc/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html):

```
>>> np.promote_types(np.uint8, int)
dtype('int32')
```

For `np.array([200], dtype=np.uint8) * 2` the array's datatype takes precedence over the scalar `int` and a `np.uint8` datatype is returned.

To address your final question about retaining the `dtype` of a scalar during operations, you'll have to restrict the datatypes of any other scalars you use to avoid NumPy's automatic `dtype` promotion:

```
>>> np.array([200], dtype=np.uint8) * np.uint8(2)
144
```

The alternative, of course, is to simply wrap the single value in a NumPy array (and then NumPy won't cast it in operations with scalars of different `dtype`).

To promote the type of an array during an operation, you could wrap any scalars in an array first:

```
>>> np.array([200], dtype=np.uint8) * np.array([2])
array([400])
```

Comment: "`dtype` just defines how bytes in memory will be interpreted by a scalar" → it also defines the way in which they're interpreted (eg. `int32` vs `float32`).

Comment: Thanks, Veedrac, I've made that sentence a little more precise.

Answer (score 3):

A numpy array contains elements of the same type, so `np.array([200],dtype=uint8)` is *an array with one value* of type `uint8`. When you do `np.uint8(200)`, you don't have an array, only *a single value*. This make a huge difference.

When performing some operation on the array, the type stays the same, irrespective of a single value overflows or not. Automatic upcasting in arrays is forbidden, as the size of the whole array has to change. This is only done if the user explicitly wants that. When performing an operation on a single value, it can easily upcast, not influencing other values.