# How to force the type of a scalar in python

Tags: python, numpy, types, casting, scalar

I would like to define a variable and have python respect that variable's type for all operations.  For example, the numpy array forces the type of its elements for all operations so the following occurs:

```
>> import numpy as np
>> foo = np.array([0], dtype=np.uint8)
>> foo[0] = 255
>> foo[0]
255
>> foo[0] += 1
>> foo[0]
0
>> foo[0] = -3
253
```

This behavior is exactly what I want, but for scalar values so that I don't have to create an array of 1 element and index into that array for every operation.  I also don't want to have to cast the value on every operation.

This is what I want:

```
>> foo = np.uint8(0)
>> foo = 257
>> foo
1
>> foo = -1
255
```

Is this possible?

To address the why: I am writing a hardware emulator and need to emulate the behavior of fixed size memories/registers (8 bit) and would like to operate on these variables and have them behave like a real 8 bit memory

This has been marked a duplicate of [Python: confusion between types and dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780878/python-confusion-between-types-and-dtypes) but I am not confused about the types, I want a scalar to behave like a uint8 without explicitely casting it for every operation, and I wondering if this is possible.  I would prefer to avoid having to type:

```
>> foo = np.uint8(value)
>> foo = np.uint8(foo + number)
>> foo += np.uint8(number)
```

this is tedious and prone to error, I would greatly prefer if I could define the type (or something akin to a type, please don't get confused by a misuse of the word type here, I am only interested in achieving the desired behavior without excessive typing or casting) and move on with writing my emulator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: confusion between types and dtypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780878/python-confusion-between-types-and-dtypes)

Comment: Thanks fjarri, but I am not confused about the types.  I am trying to get a particular behavior when manipulating a scalar and hoping that it is possible without excessive typing or casting.

Comment: Well, that's the design choice `numpy` guys made, as was mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27781185/186026). You saw yourself that you get the desired behavior for arrays, but not for scalars. As for the construction `foo = -1` it is impossible to make Python consider the current type of `foo` when making this assignment (unless you're doing some AST magic). `foo` will be overwritten by the literal `-1` of type `int` no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can't declare the type of a variable.  The variable `foo` does not have a type.  It can have a value, and that value has a type (or class).  Objects have type, variables do not.

```
>> foo = np.uint8(0)   # gives foo one value
>> foo = 257   # gives it another, unrelated value, of type 'int'
>> foo     # doesn't work this way
1
>> foo = -1   # another integer
255
```

You could define a class that has this kind of behavior, something like:

```
class Uint8(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value % 256
foo = Uint8(0)
foo = Uint8(257)
foo = Uint8(-1)
```

Your numpy examples work because `numpy` defines a `uint8` type.  And expressions like `foo[0] = 257` modify the existing variable.  They don't assign a new value to `foo`.  A review of mutable and immutable objects might help.  Lists, dictionaries, and arrays are mutable; strings, tuples and ints are immutable.

```
>> foo = np.array([0], dtype=np.uint8)
>> foo[0] = 255
>> foo[0]
255
>> foo[0] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Numpy's feature of indexing array scalars:

```
foo = np.array(0, dtype=np.uint8)  # or np.zeros((), dtype=np.uint8)
foo[()] = -1
foo
```

Which gives an output of `array(255, dtype=uint8)`.