# numpy array division floating point error inconsistent behaviour?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

To cut a long story short, I'm doing division of a numpy array of float32s which results in an overflow error for a single value. However, if I divide just the value by itself (not as an array), there's no error. I use Python2.7 in the IPython Notebook.

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr('warn')
```

My array called `kone`:

```
masked_array(data = [  1.20134726e-02   1.27720274e-03   6.29213825e-03   1.30603567e-03
   5.76360899e-23],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 0.0)
```

So then:

```
print 1, 1./kone**2 # floating point error for the last element
print 2, np.divide(1., kone**2)
print 3, 1./kone[4]**2
print 4, np.divide(1.,kone[4]**2)
print 5, np.divide(1.,np.array([kone[4]**2]))
print 6, 1./np.array([kone[4]])**2
print 7, np.divide(1, np.array([kone[4]])**2)

OUTPUT:

1 [6928.87744140625 613028.0 25258.263671875 586259.5 inf]
2 [6928.87744140625 613028.0 25258.263671875 586259.5 inf]
3 3.01030832259e+44
4 3.01030832259e+44
5 [  3.01030832e+44]
6 [ inf]
7 [ inf]

-c:12: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
-c:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
-c:17: RuntimeWarning: underflow encountered in square
-c:17: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
-c:18: RuntimeWarning: underflow encountered in square
```

<s>What is even more perplexing is if I do `arr = kone.copy()` and `print` all as above, the output is the same, as expected. However if I make a new array with the same values as `kone`:</s>

```
arr = np.ma.array([1.20134726e-02, 1.27720274e-03, 6.29213825e-03, 1.30603567e-03, 5.76360899e-23], mask=False, fill_value=0.0)
print kone
print arr
print np.isclose(kone,arr)

print 1, 1./arr[0:5]**2 
print 2, np.divide(1., arr[0:5]**2)
print 3, 1./arr[4]**2
print 4, np.divide(1.,arr[4]**2)
print 5, np.divide(1.,np.array([arr[4]**2]))
print 6, 1./np.array([arr[4]])**2
print 7, np.divide(1, np.array([arr[4]])**2)

OUTPUT:

    [  1.20134726e-02   1.27720274e-03   6.29213825e-03   1.30603567e-03
   5.76360899e-23]
[0.0120134726 0.00127720274 0.00629213825 0.00130603567 5.76360899e-23]
[ True  True  True  True  True]
1 [6928.87737841692 613028.0078115561 25258.263370509678 586259.5403880107
 3.010308326172682e+44]
2 [6928.87737841692 613028.0078115561 25258.263370509678 586259.5403880107
 3.010308326172682e+44]
3 3.01030832617e+44
4 3.01030832617e+44
5 [  3.01030833e+44]
6 [  3.01030833e+44]
7 [  3.01030833e+44]
```

Suddenly there's no floating point errors? I don't see how the last example differs from the two before. What is more, I don't see how the operation for `6,7` is any different from `3,4,5` <s>in example 1</s>?

EDIT: See comments.

Comment: Are you sure that both `kone` and `arr` are both float32s?

Comment: No! Setting the `dtype` explicitly reproduces the previous error. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: You're seeing the difference in result type between scalar / scalar operations and scalar / array operations. The rules are documented here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html#numpy.result_type

Comment: @MarkDickinson, I don't particularly understand why this happens from the docs, so if you want to write up an answer, I will accept it. I switched to using 64bit floats and I no longer get overflow problems, so this is more out of interest than anything else.

Comment: @areuexperienced: Yes, I'm not sure I follow the documentation either. I started writing an answer, then after Googling a bit, discovered that there's already a relevant question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780878/python-confusion-between-types-and-dtypes