# Convert Dataframe Column from Series to Datetime

Tags: python-3.x

Unable to convert DataFrame column to date time format.

```
from datetime import datetime

Holidays = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-01-01','2016-01-06','2016-02-09','2016-02-10','2016-03-20'], 'Expenditure':[907.2,907.3,904.8,914.6,917.3]})
Holidays['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Holidays['Date'])
type(Holidays['Date'])
```

**Output:** `pandas.core.series.Series`

Also tried

```
Holidays['Date'] = Holidays['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]') 
type(Holidays['Date'])
```

But same output

**Output:** `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting a bit mixed up. The dtypes of `Holidays['Date']` is `datetime64[ns]`

Here's how I am checking.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
Holidays = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-01-01','2016-01-06','2016-02-09','2016-02-10','2016-03-20'], 'Expenditure':[907.2,907.3,904.8,914.6,917.3]})
print ('Before converting : ' , Holidays['Date'].dtypes)
Holidays['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Holidays['Date'])
print ('After  converting : ' ,Holidays['Date'].dtypes)
```

The output is:

```
Before converting :  object
After  converting :  datetime64[ns]
```

Thought I will also share some addition information for you around types and dtypes. See more info in this link for [types-and-dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780878/python-confusion-between-types-and-dtypes)