# Type Hinting torch.float for special form type hint

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, python-typing

I have a function that can take a `typing.Union` of types including the type `torch.float`. But if I use the `typing.Union` type with `torch.float` as argument, I receive an error. Here is an example:

```
from typing import Union
import torch

def fct(my_float_or_tensor: Union[torch.float, torch.Tensor]):
    pass
```

And I get the error

```
TypeError: Union[t0, t1, ...]: each t must be a type. Got torch.float32.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Interestingly, the same problem occurs with the special type `typing.Tuple` but not if I use `torch.float` directly when type hinting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is a difference between "dtypes" and "types"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27783293/7347631). [`torch.float` is a `dtype`. For type hinting, use `torch.FloatTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#data-types) (there are also others, e.g., `DoubleTensor`, `HalfTensor` etc.)